# Using TUSB2036 for two USB 2.0 Ports

Tags: pcb-design, usb, usb-device, usb-hub

I want to use [TUSB2036](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tusb2036.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1643707898156), where the upstream is a USB2.0 port (USB2_DP, USB2_DN) comes from Intel CPU.

For my design I need two USB2.0 downstream ports for WWAN and WIFI M.2 Application.

Can this device be a good choice for my application?

Comment: It should do the job you have described with no problems. Do you have any reason to believe it won't?

Comment: I thought it was a USB 3.0 hub at first. but also USB 3.0 hub should work without any problem, because we can always use it's USB 2.0 signals. I was too cautious due to chip shortage problem, if a stock exists one should think twice why no one bought it yet.